# nodejs ffmpeg works in local but not in production

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

```
var proc = 
ffmpeg()
.input('./public/img/capture/photoframe.png')
.input( scenePath + '%04d.png')
.inputFPS(15)
.input( msgPath + '%04d.png')
.inputFPS(15)
.input( path + data + '.' + ext )
.complexFilter([
    "[3:v]scale=668:-1[scaledUGC]",
    "[0]overlay=66:155[output0]",
    "[output0][scaledUGC]overlay=66:155[output1]",
    "[output1][1]overlay=66:155[output2]",
    "[output2][2]overlay=66:155[output3]",
    "[output3][0]overlay=0:0[output4]"  
], 'output4')
.outputFPS(15)
.on('start', function(command) {
    if (env === 'development') {
        console.log(new Date());
        console.log('Start with command:'+command);
    }
})
// .on('progress', function(progress) {
//     if (env === 'development') {
//         console.log(progress.percent + "% done");
//     }
// })
.on('end', function() {
    if (env === 'development') {
        console.log(new Date());
        console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
    }

    var gifMaker = 
    ffmpeg()
    .input('./public/_ugc/' + data + '.mp4')
    .save('./public/_ugc/' + data + '.gif');

    res.send({
        status: "success",
        uid: data
    });

})
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);

    res.send({
        status: "err",
        uid: "err_video"
    });
})
.save('./public/_ugc/' + data + '.mp4');
```

I have the above code that can successfully generate a 5s video in my local Mac.

However, when I push the code to the production Ubuntu, it can only generate a 1s video only.

There is no error in the Ubuntu side. I wonder if I missed anything.

I also wonder should I preload the source images first?

node v12.13.0

ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0

ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: If it generates a video then it must be working correctly. Are you sure the images (input) is the same between local and prod?

Comment: @laggingreflex yes i think so. otherwise i think error will be shown as well

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?